# Prevent access to folder of subdomain on main domain

Tags: web-services, .htaccess, cpanel

I have few websites on my host. Most of them have their own domain.

I want to prevent access to my subdomain folder via maindomain.com/subdomain .

I want to make it able to open only via subdomain.maindomain.com

Disable access if possible, or just redirect it to subdomain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if not already blog.website.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.website\.com$ [NC] 
#if request is for blog/, go to blog.website.com
RewriteRule ^blog/$ http://blog.website.com [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Codeigniter has it's own rewrite system, you might have conflict there.

Answer (score 2):

htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch ^/subdomain/(.*)$ http://subdomain.mysite.com/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me:
RedirectMatch ^/subdomain(.*)$ https://subdomain.example.com